# WPF and AOT: error NETSDK1168: WPF is not supported or recommended with trimming enabled

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to publish a WPF application (a blank application to try) with the AOT option, but I get this error: error NETSDK1168: WPF is not supported or recommended with trimming enabled.

In issues of the github, I have read that I can disabled the warnings setting in the project file the parameter <_SuppressWpfTrimError>true</_SuppressWpfTrimError>, but it is not available in my case.

I am using visual studio 2022, v17.4 and NET 7.

Is there some way to can use AOT with WPF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is not supported and I wouldn't get my hopes up that it ever will be:

[.NET 7 Preview 3 Is All About Native AOT](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/04/15/net-7-preview-3.aspx)

> Native AOT is not for all projects, though, and Microsoft says in .NET
> 7 it will primarily help developers who build console apps or native
> libraries.
>
> It's incredibly disappointing that it's not supported by WPF /
> Winforms (dunno about MAUI). That makes it only a console / library
> feature. That means I cannot use it in any of my larger applications
> but for those it only matters. I don't need startup improvement for
> tiny console projects.
>
> We plan to look into expanding the scenarios where NativeAOT is a good
> fit over time. It's a function of time and resources. It is already
> possible to use WinForms with NativeAOT, but it requires some polish
> and won't be advertised as a supported scenario because of that. I
> suggest following a .NET community member who helped to make a lot of
> progress on this over the years: Andrey Kurdyumov --
> https://twitter.com/Kurdiumov. Here's one of his articles where he
> made tweaks to various open source WinForms apps to make them
> compatible with NativeAOT in the form it is right now:
> https://codevision.medium.com/again-winforms-and-nativeaot-fd068425cc13.
> It can give you an idea where are we now.